# Call and use a jquery plugin inside a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im trying call another jquery plugin inside my plugin but not works, if i write it outside it works correctly;

in this case this plugin has "onInit" function, but it do nothing inside my plugin and i cant log anything on debug.

Can someone help me to understand it.

```
 $.fn.mytest= function( options ) {
    var PP = $.fn.issamtest;
    var container = $(this);
    var e = this;
    var inputs = [];


    var defaults = {
        textColor: "#000",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        works: [],
        service:null

    };

    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    //i want call another plugin like "bootstrap switch" in this code
    $('#xdjaja').bootstrapSwitch({
        onInit:function(){
            $('body').html('asd');
        }
    });  

       PP.start();

};
```

Comment: How/where are you calling the `mytest` plugin?

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#containerservices").mytest({
      works: works,
      service:service
  });
}); @Santi

Comment: You normally can. There can be many reason why it doesn't work for you. 2 versions of jQuery loaded, `bootstrapSwitch` not loaded when you call your plugin, syntax error anywhere else, element removed from the DOM, etc...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes it works, the plugin is loaded, but on events nothing happends, and i cant access `bootstrapSwitch`  properties inside my plugin

Comment: There are no console errors? And you're loading the `bootstrapSwitch` plugin *before* your own, correct?

Comment: @Santi Nothing in console, no errors.. no info. and yes its loaded before my plugin